# I would like to see an example web method that passes an array of objects from aspx webservice

Tags: java, android, asp.net, json, web-services

im trying to self learn how to consume an aspx web service from android.

In this case im trying to pass an array of objects from a web service.

I would like to take a look at a sample [web method] that passes an array of objects.

and if possible a sample code of how the array passed by the web service is consumed by the android application. (the java code)

Any code posted would be highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JSON to get array of objects in Android

so Now, let me start to give step by step demo for parsing the same JSON resoponse:

Step – 1:

create a JSONObject with the received response string:

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJSONResponse);`

Step – 2:

Get the main object from the created json object by using getJSONObject() method:

`JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("FirstObject");`

Step – 3:

Now this FirstObject contains 2 strings namely “attr1″,”attr2″ and a object namely “sub”.
So get 2 strings by using getString() method.

`String attr1 = object.getString("attr1");
String attr2 = object.getString("attr2");`

and get a sub object by using the same getJSONObject() method as we have used above:

`JSONObject subObject = object.getJSONObject("sub");`

Step – 4:

Now this “sub” sub-object contains 1 array namely “sub1″. So we can get this JSON array by using
getJSONArray() method:

`JSONArray subArray = subObject.getJSONArray("sub1");`

Now, we just need to process this array same as simple string array:

`for(int i=0; i&lt;subArray.length(); i++)
{
     strParsedValue+="\n"+subArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sub1_attr").toString();
}`